# jQuery function as a property value of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I have an object within an object which contains a property whose value is a jQuery function:

```
var fields = {
    id: {},
    timeStarted: {},
    duration: {},
    status: {},
    name: {
        field: $("#companyName"),
        changeEvent: $("#companyName").on("click", function(){
            alert("bazinga!");
        })
    }
};
```

I also have another function which goes through all values found within `fields` and tries to register the change events:

```
function registerChangeEvents(){
    $.each(fields, function(field, v){
        $.each(v, function(prop, vv){
            // check which property the loop is on: if changeEvent
            if (prop == "changeEvent"){
                vv();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

When I run `registerChangeEvents()` however, the console returns `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`. I can wrap the value of `changeEvent` with a `function(){...}` and that would make it a function which will run fine. For some reason that doesn't seem like the right approach, though.

Please do let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a function, it is the result of invocing those jQuery functions (which turns out to be a jQuery wrapper object). Wrapping the invocation in an anonymous function *is* the way to go (unless you want to use `$.fn.click.bind($("#companyName"), alert.bind(window, "bazinga!"))`)

Answer (score 2):

When you have this:

```
changeEvent: $("#companyName").on("click", function(){
    alert("bazinga!");
})
```

The code is executed immediately and the result of `.on()` is the original selected objects...which is just `$("#companyName")`. So `changeEvent` is set to a jQuery object, containing the element with the `id` "companyName".

I would change the `name` to be:

```
name: {
    field: "#companyName",
    changeEvent: function(){
        alert("bazinga!");
    }
}
```

and then change your function to be:

```
function registerChangeEvents(){
    $.each(fields, function(prop, v){
        var field, changeEvent;
        $.each(v, function(propp, vv){
            if (propp === "field") field = vv;
            if (propp === "changeEvent") changeEvent = vv;
        });
        if (field && changeEvent) $(field).on("change", changeEvent);
    });
}
```

I'm confused about 1 thing - you call it "changeEvent", but the `event` in your original code was for "click".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assume that my first suggestion (of wrapping the `changeEvent` value within a javascript function) would be best, in that case? Also, I apologize for not mentioning this earlier, but `registerChangeEvents()` is to be fired after a certain ajax call has been made.

Comment: Different `fields` will have different `changeEvents` that are not restricted to just `click`s, that is why I called it that. For example, I am using Bootstrap's pseudo-radio buttons that don't fire a native change event.

Comment: The `registerChangeEvents()` is called so that I can have those change events in place for all the fields that I will call via Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to register the change events, you need to wrap the click handler attachment:

```
name: {
    field: $("#companyName"),
    changeEvent: function() {
        this.field.on("click", function(){
            alert("bazinga!");
        });
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
$.each(fields, function(field, v) {
    if ($.isFunction(v.changeEvent)) {
        v.changeEvent();
    }
}
```